# how to group string elements for a desired length

Tags: ruby, algorithm, math, mathematical-optimization

I want to create subsets of a string dataset. For example, I have 150 words in different lengths. I need to distribute them to the groups which have max length of 100 charachter. I couldn't find any way of doing this in optimal way. For this case minimum number of new groups.

Since I am not familiar with general format of stack sorry for complicated question.

Websites array is a sample of my data, complete one just contains more websites. What I am trying to do is putting these websites to new arrays which have 255 length limit. And I am trying to do is in most efficient way, by creating minimum number of new arrays.

```
websites=["0n-line.tv","100dollars-seo.com","12masterov.com","1pamm.ru","4webmasters.org","5forex.ru","7makemoneyonline.com","acads.net"]

websiteslength =[10, 18, 14, 8, 15, 9, 20, 9, 10, 11]
```

This is the code I wrote so far, yet it doesn't do what I need exactly.

```
while total <= 255
  puts total
  total += websiteslength[y]
  total += 1
  if total <= 255
    y += 1
  else
    total -= a[y]
    y += 1
    total += a[y]
    if total == 255
      #total has reached to 255 start new sub-array
    else
      total -= a[y]
      y += 1
      total += a[y]
      if total == 255 
      #total has reached to 255 start new sub-array
      else
      total -= a[y]
      y += 1
      total += a[y]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post sample data / desired result?

Comment: @suslov I am reducing number just for simplifying, 100 character would be long. Lets say my words are "dog, mice, table, desk, house, separation, book, fly, pencil" , and I want every sub-group from these keywords to be length of 20. Sub-Set1= "dog, mice, fly, separation" >>20.  Sub-Set2 ="table, house, book, pencil" >> 20. Sub-set3 ="desk" >>4

Comment: Use the [**edit** link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31465799/edit) to add relevant information right into the question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When asking for help solving a problem, we expect certain things: a minimal sample of input data, the minimum code that demonstrates the problem you're having, an example of the data you expect to return. Without that we're left guessing what you mean for any of those. When you tell us none of those things we have nothing to work with and your question will be closed. Please take the time to add the necessary information, which helps us help you.

Comment: It sounds like your problem is a classic one: the [bin-packing problem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem). See the link for a discussion of algorithms for solving it. If the data set is not too large, you may be able to produce a (guaranteed) optimal solution; else you may have to rely on heuristic methods, which hopefully produce "good", though not necessarily optimal, solutions.